# Angular observable subsribe to a property

Tags: angular, rxjs

This is a simple view of how i have set it up, the images array is actually inside a formgroup, which is in the end passed back to the C# backend

I wish to check if the `images` array contains more than 4 elements, otherwise set `canAdd` as false and now allow anymore images to be added to the `images` array, once an image gets removed from the array it should then be allowed again

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
  images = []
  canAdd: Observable<boolean>
  

constructor() { }
}
```

How do i set up the subscription ? between this array and the observable ?

I am adding to the image array like this

```
onFileChanged(files) {
  // Check here the observable if it canAdd

  if (files.length === 0)
    return;

  var mimeType = files[0].type;
  if (mimeType.match(/image\/*/) == null)
    return;

  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
  reader.onload = (_event) => {
    this.images.push(reader.result);
  }
}
```

Comment: This might help you. The problem is, you didn't try anything. Check this, it will give you clues ->  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52721230/how-to-access-the-object-in-the-observable-list

Comment: How are you adding the images? are they coming from api or you're uploading?

Comment: Can you tell more about your specific usecase? If I understand it correctly, I would change images to an observable (if it comes from an api) and canAdd to a subject (it could be behavior subject). Then in ngOnInit I would subscribe to the images observable, check for its length and emit true/false on subject depending on the length of the images. Also it would be good to put all logic into a dedicated service. But it all depends how you're fetching images and how you're using it. If you need to modify images, it also could be a subject so you could emit new values on question add/remove.

Comment: The images array is actually inside a formgroup, but i have simplified it a bit here, i just want to be able to show/hide the input tag which adds images if the image array is above 4 and show it  if its less than that

Comment: Basically, as @Matt said you should check the length of the array, and based on that your logic of hiding and showing should work. Add your code where you have images in the form group if you need any help there to understand how to check the length of the array and handle the logic.

Comment: Are you handling uploading and hiding/showing in the same component? If yes and if images is a public property, you can handle it with simple ngIf, for example something similar to this: <input type="file" (change)="onFileChanged($event)" multiple *ngIf="images?.length < 4">. In this way you do not need canAdd but I would make it more reactive and handle it in a dedicated service. This service would handle images upload + canAdd value change emit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know your specific usecase but depending on your logic, you can handle it in few different ways.

For example if you are handling upload and display in the same component and images is a public property on this component, you could do it like this:

```
<input type="file" (change)="onFileChanged($event)" multiple *ngIf="images?.length < 4">
```

If you are doing it somewhere else, then I would move logic to a separate service which would handle the upload process and tell the subscribers to hide/show input when the image array changes, e.g.:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UploadService {

  constructor() { }

    //if you want to hold images here
    private images: any[] = [];

  //use this to emit values to show/hide input
  private canAddSubject: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(true);
  readonly canAdd$: Observable<boolean> = this.canAddSubject.asObservable();

  //you can use another subject and observable if you want subscribe to images array changes
  //this way will allow you to handle it in a more reative way
  private imagesSubject: BehaviorSubject<any[]> = new BehaviorSubject<any[]>([]);
  readonly images$: Observable<any[]> = this.imagesSubject.asObservable();

  public onFileChanged(files): void {
    
      this.images.length > 4
        ? this.canAddSubject.next(false)
        : this.canAddSubject.next(true);

        //rest of the code omitted for brevity
    }
}
```

Then just inject service to your component and listen to canAdd$ changes with async pipe, e.g.:

```
<input type="file" (change)="onFileChanged($event)" multiple *ngIf="uploadService.canAdd$ | async">
```